# Is the Login control buggy?

Tags: c#, asp.net, layout, postback, login-control

From the documentation here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login.layouttemplate.aspx i had customized the user interface of login control through layout template like below

```
<LayoutTemplate>
                    <h3 class="login-title page-header">
                        <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="loginHeading" Text="Sign-in"></asp:Literal>
                    </h3>
                    <div class="clearfix">
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblUserName" Text="Username" AssociatedControlID="UserName"></asp:Label>
                        <div class="input">
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="UserName"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="rfvTxtUserName" ErrorMessage="Username is required"
                                ControlToValidate="UserName" Text="Username is required"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix">
                        <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Password" AssociatedControlID="Password"></asp:Label>
                        <div class="input">
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Password" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="rfvTxtPassword" ErrorMessage="Password is required"
                                ControlToValidate="Password" Text="Password is required"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix">
                        <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Remember Me" AssociatedControlID="RememberMe"></asp:Label>
                        <div class="input">
                            <input type="checkbox" runat="server" id="RememberMe" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="actions action-fix">
                        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="Login" Text="Login" CssClass="btn success small" />
                        <input type="reset" class="btn small" value="reset" />
                    </div>
                </LayoutTemplate>
```

as you can see i did name the control ID as required by the control. Also i use CSS Friendly control adapter for rendering the Login control.

#### The Problem

It just happens after user types username and password and submits the details nothing happens the page just reloads causing a postback.

- What am i doing wrong here

**info**:
more problem seems to be more prominent for users using `LoginControlAdapter` look here http://forums.asp.net/t/1043974.aspx/2/10

Comment: Is the user being Authenticated? Have you turned on Page Tracing to see what is happening, or stepped through the postback to follow the Event paths? You have only posted code for the Layout, what about the actual Login control settling which are the key properties!

Comment: @Lloyd i certainly found out that the state had been causes by using Login control adapter used in the CSS Friendly Control adapters package. The state of the project is pathetic, the project site is no longer maintained and no information is provided that latest build is to be got from Codeplex which also has this issue

Comment: I dont think I would be using code that was 5 years old given that Html5 and CSS 3 has changed so much since then.

Comment: @Lloyd but i am using age old .NET 2.0 ASP.NET 2.0 due to my organization's stupidness!! anyways thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must be missing CommandName paramter

```
  <asp:button id="Login" CommandName="Login" runat="server" Text="Login"></asp:button>
```

Comment: i did try it immediately after posting this seems during authenticate event username and password come empty

Answer (score 0):

Try adding command name to your login button;

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="Login" Text="Login" CssClass="btn success small" CommandName="Login" />
```

Comment: i did try it immediately after posting this seems during authenticate event username and password come empty

Comment: it must be something else.. check the code at msdn http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login.layouttemplate.aspx